# Burninate beginnner tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup, meta-tags

[beginnner](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginnner)

no seriously, three *n*'s.

I removed it from the questions using it, as beginner (even when written correctly) is a meta-tag. As it is still in the system and usable by other questions in the future, I suggest to burninate the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Meta Stack Overflow on [what happens to zombie tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags):

> Tags not associated with any question are pruned every 24 hours on the
>   backend.
>
> Tag counts shown on the tags tab and in the tags autocomplete are also
>   calculated once daily.

No need to burninate (or create a synonym either).

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, good to know, thanks!